# Correct way of invoking a phone call from within the app in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-logcat

I have a small piece of code which is basically supposed to make a phone call when a button is pushed. I looked it up online and all the sources basically gave the same code. But for some reason this code doesn't work. It makes the app crash but the LogCat doesn't display anything (meaning the log is completely blank). I should also mention that in my manifest file I did add the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name = "andriod.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

The code I have is as follows. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
phoneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                final Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:232131232"));
                ContactUs.this.startActivity(callIntent);
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    Log.e("Dialing", "call Failed!", e);

                }
            }           
        });
```

Comment: i just took that code you have there and put it into a project, hooked up a button and it worked.  Instead of ContactUs.this.startActivity i just put startActivity(callIntent);

Comment: That's interesting because mine doesn't. It throws Security Exception and appears to have a problem with startActivity (callIntent); I also have some other buttons on the same screen where I want this button to be. Do you think that could be an issue?

Comment: So I just replaced ACTION_CALL with ACTION_DIAL which is working for all intents and purposes but I still don't know why ACTION_CALL wouldn't work for me :(

Comment: I see a typo in `andriod.permission.CALL_PHONE` - is that actually how it's spelled in your manifest?  (the `i` and `o` are swapped)

Comment: The reason replacing ACTION_CALL with ACTION_DIAL worked is because ACTION_DIAL does not require `CALL_PHONE` permission. With ACTION_DIAL, the native dialer will be shown with the number you specified and the user has to press dial to continue. This doesn't require `CALL_PHONE` permission. `ACTION_CALL` would immediately make the device call the number (you *will* need the permission for that). As Daniel DiPaolo mentioned, it is more likely you misspelt the manifest entry (Android lint really ought to catch that sort of thing).

Answer (score 3):

You spelt android wrong the second time...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to add the user-permission for making a phone call.  I believe the permission is:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>`

in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from an Activity class I am currently testing on my HTC Desire -

```
okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
       intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + getPhoneNumber()));
       startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```

I suggest changing `ContactUs.this.startActivity(callIntent);` to `startActivity(callIntent);` and testing it again.